# Find date gap between two events based on other column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Dataset like below :

How can I find  the time gap by day between the first hire date and terminated date  for each employee No and show the result within a new column called FinalTenure in front of the terminated value row and leave other if condition not true as null ?

| employee No | Event date | Event Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2021-10-12 | First Hire |
| 103 | 2021-11-02 | First Hire |
| 102 | 2022-01-01 | Terminated |
| 102 | 2021-12-12 | Shift Change |
| 101 | 2021-12-03 | First Hire |
| 103 | 2021-11-05 | Terminated |
| 101 | 2021-12-04 | Terminated |
| 105 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire |
| 106 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire |
| 102 | 2022-03-29 | Second Hire |
| 107 | 2021-05-04 | First Hire |
| 108 | 2022-04-04 | First Hire |
| 109 | 2022-03-03 | Terminated |
| 109 | 2021-12-29 | First Hire |
| 109 | 2022-04-01 | Second Hire |
| 109 | 2022-01-10 | Shift Change |

Using window function is preferable .Thank you in advance.

Comment: While we're happy to try and assist, StackOverflow isn't a free code writing or do my homework service.  You're expected to demonstrate you've made an effort to solve the problem first by posting a) sample data b) the sql you've tried, and c) the outcome (all as text *not* screen shots). Preferably in the form of a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk).

Answer (score 1):

your data.I added some sample data in order to distinguish `First Hire` and `Second Hire` and their respective termination.

```
create table Dataset1  (
   employee_No       INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Event_date        DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Event_Description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Dataset1
(employee_No,Event_date,Event_Description) VALUES
(102,'2021-10-12','First Hire'),
(103,'2021-11-02','First Hire'),
(102,'2022-01-01','Terminated'),
(102,'2021-12-12','Shift Change'),
(101,'2021-12-03','First Hire'),
(103,'2021-11-05','Terminated'), 
(101,'2021-12-04','Terminated'),
(105,'2022-02-26','First Hire'),
(106,'2022-02-26','First Hire'),
(102,'2022-03-29','Second Hire'),
(107,'2021-05-04','First Hire'),
(108,'2022-04-04','First Hire'),
(109,'2022-03-03','Terminated'),
(109,'2021-12-29','First Hire'),
(109,'2022-04-01','Second Hire'),
(109,'2022-01-10','Shift Change'),
(109,'2022-05-03','secondTerminated'),--added value for test
(102,'2022-05-03','secondTerminated');--added value for test
```

you should use `Subquery`,`Join` and `Datediff` to get your desired result.

```
SELECT b.employee_no,
       b.event_date,
       b.event_description,
       a.startdate,
       a.enddate,
       Datediff(day, startdate, enddate) FinalTenure
FROM   (SELECT employee_no,
               Min(event_date) AS StartDate,
               Max(event_date) AS EndDate
        FROM   dataset1
        GROUP  BY employee_no) a
       JOIN (SELECT employee_no,
                    event_date,
                    event_description
             FROM   dataset1) b
         ON a.employee_no = b.employee_no
```

however I recommend to use `pivot` and then use `Datediff` as your  function to get your desired result.

```
SELECT employee_no,
       [first hire],
       [shift change],
       [second hire],
       [terminated],
       [secondterminated],
       Datediff(day, [first hire], [terminated]) FinalTenure1,
       Datediff(day,[second hire], [secondterminated]) FinalTenure2
FROM   (SELECT employee_no,
               event_date,
               event_description
        FROM   dataset1 yt) src
       PIVOT ( Max(event_date)
             FOR event_description IN ([First Hire],
                                       [Shift Change],
                                       [Second Hire],
                                       [Terminated],
                                       [secondTerminated]) ) piv;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4e6457d19c6f404d2ced45f88d3fb79)